# Brief description for Jar version in Nexus repository

Tags: maven, deployment, jar, repository, nexus

We have a local Nexus repository in which we store the libraries and components we develop. I'm looking for a way to briefly document changes in each version, such that they can be easily seen by anyone accessing the repository.

The reason: Sometimes a jar will be updated, not because the code has changed, but because it needs to refer to a new version of an existing dependency. This can break other applications so I'd ideally like to have some listing like this:

```
SomeLibrary-1.0.0.jar
...
SomeLibrary-1.0.7.jar
SomeLibrary-1.0.8.jar - now uses OtherLibrary-2.3.1, previous versions of SomeLibrary used OtherLibrary-1.9.11
```

Is there any way to add a description of a deployment to a jar file when I deploy it to Nexus?

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a additional file to the module using the [BuildHelper](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) plugin?

## Update

Nexus professional has a support for [editing and viewing metadata](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/custom-metadata-plugin.html) associated with each artifact. The following support question describes how this data can be pushed to Nexus:

- [How to add additional metadata to an artifact stored in Nexus](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/21474027-How-can-I-add-additional-metadata-to-an-artifact-stored-in-Nexus-)

Comment: Could you explain how adding an additional file to the module will help me put brief descriptions of a particular version of a module into the Nexus repository?

Comment: Mark means that you could e.g. have a release notes file that has these remarks in it and is deployed as another file into the repository. And the build helper plugin can do that for you with the attach goal ...

Comment: @ManfredMoser: Ah, interesting idea. Is it possible to generate the file on the fly? Ideally I'd do something like `mvn deploy SomeLibrary -DversionDescription='this version makes use of the new version of OtherLibrary'` and the value for `${versionDescription}` would be in this attached file. Also, do you know if Nexus would be able to display this?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I have updated my answer. If you use the custom metadata file you can edit metadata via the UI, but I'm not aware of a way to autogenerate this file.

Comment: You can use the Maven resources plugin to filter the metadata file and provide the property on the fly on the command line like you want.

Comment: And yes.. if you use the custom metadata plugin as Mark suggests (which is a feature of Nexus Professional) then you can view, edit and search for the metadata. If you just want the info somewhere you could attach any file (like a releasenotes txt file or whatever and then users have to download it to view it)